# derative of Taylor expansion

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm reading [this part of article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Keypoint_localization) about key points localization in image processing, and there is something I don't quite understand, mathematically it's this, 
$$D(w) = D + {\frac{\partial D}{\partial w}}^T w + \frac{1}{2}w^T\frac{\partial^2 D}{\partial w^2}w$$

this is the **Taylor expansion** up to the quadratic order, and $w = (x,y,\sigma)$, I need to find the local extrema, which means I should take the derivative of $D(w)$, and set it to $0$, solve the equation to find out the local extrema points $\hat w$.

And according to another article (not from wiki), it says
$$\hat w = -{\frac{\partial^2 D}{\partial w^2}}^{-1}\frac{\partial D}{\partial w}$$

Why? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your problem starts with what you term `the derivative of $D(w)$.'

The function $D$ is a *scalar* function of several variables $(w_1, \ldots , w_N)$, so to it corresponds a gradient $\nabla D = (\partial D/\partial w_1 , \ldots , \partial D/\partial w_N)$; that's what needs to be set to zero.

You might also be getting confused by the notation; keep in mind that the derivatives in the right-hand side are evaluated at some fixed point (let's say $x^0$) & $D$ in the left-hand side is evaluated at some other point $x$. As the article you link states, $w = x-x^0$ is the *offset*. Hence, the correct formula is

$$
D(x) = D + (\nabla_x D(x^0))^{\rm T} (x-x^0) + \frac{1}{2} (x-x^0)^{\rm T} \Delta_x D(x^0) (x-x^0) .
$$

Now, the elementary way of calculating the gradient (which, again, you need to set to zero) is by writing the above expression out in the form
$$
D(x) = D + \sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-x_n^0) \frac{\partial D(x^0)}{\partial x_n} + \sum_{m=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N (x_m-x_m^0) (x_n-x_n^0) \frac{\partial^2 D(x^0)}{\partial x_m \partial x_n}
$$
and then taking each derivative - e.g., $\partial D(x)/\partial x_1$ - of both sides of the equation by hand. (Better do it now.) This results in
$$
\nabla_x D(x) = \nabla_x D(x^0) + \Delta_x D(x^0) (x-x^0) ,
$$
which is, in fact, Taylor's formula for the gradient (as expected).

Finally, set the left-hand side to zero & solve for $x-x^0$ ($w$, in your notation) to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you have write it it appears that this is the Maclaurin expansion, i.e the Taylor expansion around zero. Then for the expression to be clear let's write it

$$D(w) = D(0) + {\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}^T w + \frac{1}{2}w^T\frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}w $$

The first term and the derivatives present in the RHS are *numbers*, already evaluated at the center of the expansion (here, zero), and do not contain the variable $w$.

So 
$$\frac {\partial D(w)}{\partial w} = 0 + {\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}  + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}^T+\frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2} \right)w$$

The first term is zero because $D(0)$ is a number, while in the second the derivative is transposed by the standard rules for differentiating vectors/matrices, from which the last term also comes. The matrix of second derivatives is symmetric (it includes the cross-partials also), so

$$\frac {\partial D(w)}{\partial w} = {\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}  + \frac{1}{2}2\frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}w$$

Set it equal to zero

$$\hat w: \qquad {\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}  + \frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}w =0$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad   \frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}w =-{\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad   \hat w =-\frac{\partial^2 D(0)}{\partial w^2}^{-1}{\frac{\partial D(0)}{\partial w}}$$

...which is your equation.